# Exporting map to image using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, georeferencing

I have a transparent raster on top of a hillshade.

I want to Project - Import/Export - Export map to image using PyQGIS:

[image]

I need to be able to set extent, scale, dpi and the output needs to be georeferenced.

I have followed [PyQGIS: Render (Print/Save) a Layer as an Image](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-render-print-save-a-layer-as-an-image/) to get an output but the output has no coordinate system set.

How can I export the image including this?

```
img = QImage(QSize(3000, 3000), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
img.setDotsPerMeterX(1)
img.setDotsPerMeterY(1)

# create map settings
ms = QgsMapSettings()

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

# set layers to render
layers = list(reversed([lyr for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]))
ms.setLayers(layers)

# set extent
rect = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
rect.scale(1.1)
ms.setExtent(rect)

# set ouptut size
ms.setOutputSize(img.size())

# setup qgis map renderer
render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
render.start()
render.waitForFinished()
p.end()

# save the image
img.save('/home/bera/Desktop/test_render.png')

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an external world file, which provides the georeferencing information for the raster image you export.

```
...

# save the image
img.save('/home/bera/Desktop/test_render.png')

# world file content
pgw_content = QgsMapSettingsUtils.worldFileContent(ms)

with open('/home/bera/Desktop/test_render.pgw', "w") as f:
    f.write(pgw_content)

print('Done')
```