# Exporting vector layer as TIFF using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, export, vector-layer

I have a layer named *'result'* which I want to export as a georeferenced TIFF file.

[image: result layer]

I have a layer named *'layer'* which is just a vector polygon (it has to be there). The best code I've found to do that is the following:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('result')[0]

# Define the output file path
output_file = my_folder_path + "/myimg.tif"

layer_to_hide = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")[0]
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer_to_hide.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)

# Export the layer to GeoTIFF
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/driver", "GTiff")
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/DstFile", output_file)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/Layers", [layer.id()])
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/extent", layer.extent().toString())
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/width", str(iface.mapCanvas().size().width()))
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/height", str(iface.mapCanvas().size().height()))
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/Renderer", "pal")
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("ImageEncoder", "/Renderer/Settings/Filters", [layer.id()])
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(output_file)
```

The problem is that the newly created *myimg.tif* shows the polygon from the *'layer'* layer when I don't want that.

[image: myimg.tif shown on QGIS]

I've tried unsuccessfully to adapt the code to get rid of the polygon on the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412529/export-map-to-image-using-pyqgis) can help